# Do tank bullets inflict damage on other tanks and jets in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

When I'm in a tank and manning the gun on top, I'm often confused as to what I should be doing when an enemy jet or tank starts getting to close to my position. I often open fire on them and try to inflict as much damage as possible. However, as far as I can tell, they're not doing anything at all. Am I mistaken, and can I actually hurt jets and tanks using tank bullets(not shells)? Or should I be focusing on checking for nearby engies or other soldiers?

Comment: So is BF3 all 'realistic' so you can't destroy a tank with an M16 or the like?

Comment: Yes, pretty much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bullets from a tank's secondary position will inflict damage on most vehicles and all infantry.

Damage to aerial vehicles is fair, it's definitely worth shooting them to at least annoy them, and possibly disable them if they stick around long enough.

Damage to enemy armour is non-existant, and you're better off looking for enemy engineers repairing the tank, or scanning around for any sneaky engineers/supports who are looking for an easy kill on a distracted tank.

Comment: the anti-air vehicle chaingun is about the only exception to "bullets don't hurt tanks". And even then it takes quite a while to do *real* damage.

Comment: While shooting at a chopper with a mounted machines gun won't do that much damange it will cause the pilot to see out cover. Keep an eye on them though, as you never know if they'll circle round behind you and hammer you with missiles.

Comment: Also, the secondary driver HMG unlock (50 cal) is capable of damaging vehicles, so it is effective to use that on all but heavy armor as well as infantry, so that you can still drive while attacking (use the MG while your main gun is reloading). It is also more accurate at range than the LMG but the rate of fire is rather slow.

Comment: @Jeff: The manned gun at the bottom of the helicopter can take a tank out in about two seconds of continuous fire

Comment: @blue that is a 20mm cannon on the helicopter gunner position, it does not fire "bullets" per the question.

Comment: Note that with the latest patch, they made the top gun on tanks much stronger against air vehicles(it's completely feasible to disable a helicopter that's not acting smart now), while making it slightly weaker against infantry. Also, I'm 99% sure that the top gun will never hurt a heavily armored land vehicle by even a percentage point

Comment: @Earlz Yeah I've updated my answer based on the damage that the bullets do to jets/helis and also tanks. Dunno why I thought the gun hurts tanks, coz it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

bullets from machine guns do not affect tanks or APCs.  They DO affect aircraft if the aircraft are close enough. They are most effective against scout helicopters, far less effective against attack helicopters, and if you can hit a jet, they are somewhat effective, but really not worth shooting because the jets get out of the kill zone so quickly.

As others have said, you are best off shooting at soldiers on foot or in jeeps so you don't get C4'd or blown up by RPG.

One thing also to remember is that if you get a lucky shot through the canopy of ANY aircraft, you can also get a kill. I have seen snipers do that on rare occasion, and have been killed that way in a helicopter. You will also find scumbag teammates occasionally teamkill you with a rifle when you're in an airplane or chopper just before takeoff: They scumbag teamkiller will shoot you through the canopy of the jet or glass of the helo.  That is also the way some snipers abuse spawns: They camp so they can see the planes or helo spawns and shoot the pilots as soon as they spawn in the aircraft.  That is not possible with a tank, though. Bullets do nothing to armor. And as another person said, remember that the gun on an attack helicopter is an armor-piercing cannon; the gun on the scout helo is just a machine gun, but even so, it will destroy a tank after about 6 full-magazine unloads on the tank. Any tank stupid enough to just sit there while you shoot it up deserves to get destroyed. But more likely you will as you move low-level within range of other tanks, SAMs, and even ground soldiers shooting into your helo.